# Как правильно расставить знаки? Объясните

Tags: пунктуация

**Если со стороны девушки всё было ясно (?) она любила его за то, что он для неё сделал (?) то сторона мужчины была непонятна.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Предлагается вариант:

*Если со стороны девушки всё было ясно — **она любила его за то, что он для неё сделал**, то сторона мужчины была непонятна.*

**Пояснение**

**Основная структура:** СПП с придаточным условия  (двойной союз ЕСЛИ...ТО), там ставится запятая.

**Придаточное условия** имеет сложный состав, тире отделяет **присоединительную** конструкцию с пояснительным значением (обособление тире). **Второе тире** не ставится, так как дальше заканчивается придаточное условия и стоит **запятая** перед главной частью *СПП*.

У предложения **сложная грамматика** (4 предикативные основы). Специального правила нет, так что приходится комбинировать отдельные темы.

Comment: А вместо тире не может стоять двоеточие? Если пользоваться правилом, что это сложное бессоюзное предложение, где вторая часть носит пояснительное значение («Если со стороны девушки всё было ясно: (что именно?) она любила его за то, что…»)? Как понять, что эта конструкция именно присоединительная и нужно тире?

Answer (score 1):

**Ответ на комментарий**

1. Рассмотрим  предложение:

*Со стороны девушки **всё было ясно**: она любила его за то, что он для неё сделал* (**пояснение**).

Можно поставить двоеточие или тире (выбор автора по контексту). Здесь три предикативные основы и два блока **[по Лопатину](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=136#pp136).** Основная связь обозначена **двоеточием или тире**.

**[Розенталь § 72. Вариативные знаки препинания.   Двоеточие — тире](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=189#pp189)**

Двоеточие — **сильный** знак, и он здесь вполне на месте. Его обычно выбирают именно для обозначения именно **основной** связи.

2. А в заданном предложении основным знаком является **запятая** (если…то).  Было бы странно использовать двоеточие в предложении,  которое **входит в состав**  СПП с придаточным условия. А вот тире — **универсальный** знак,   он подходит как для  БСП,  так  и для **присоединительных** конструкций любого вида. **[§ 24. Присоединительные конструкции](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=120#pp120).**